# Lower bound on union of selection across group

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics

**The setting is as following:**

1. There are N numbers marked 1....N
2. There are N nodes marked T1,...TN
3. Each node selects (by some internal criteria which is not shared) exactly 2/3 of the N numbers and broadcasts its decision.
4. The result of the algorithm is the union of numbers which were selected by **at least 2/3 of the nodes**.

I'm trying to calculate a lower bound on the size of the resulting union.

My intuition is that at least 2/3 of the numbers must always appear in the union, but am having trouble in formalising the proof...

In the "worst case" each node will select a different set of 2/3 of the numbers, causing **all** the numbers to be part of the union.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is not correct.  Given that *N* is divisible by 3 (otherwise a node could not select *exactly* 2/3 of the numbers), the key to figuring out the actual lower bound is this:

> The count of numbers selected at least *2N/3* times is minimized by *maximizing* the count of numbers selected *exactly 2N/3 - 1* times.

Let *k* be the count of numbers selected at lest *2N/3* times.  Since there are *2N<sup>2</sup>/3* selections in total, and a number can be selected at most *N* times, we have:

*2N<sup>2</sup>/3 - (N-k)(2N/3 - 1) <= kN*

Solving for *k*, we get:

*k >= 3N / (N+3)*

It seems there is no lower bound on the proportion.  If *N* is large, we can have *k=3*.

We can have *k < 2N/3* as long as *N>=6*.  Let's try it.  We have 6 nodes and each one selects 4 numbers.  For each of the 6 numbers, here are the nodes that select it:

```
number1: 123456
number2: 123456
number3: 123
number4: 456
number5: 123
number6: 456
```

Only 1/3 of the numbers are selected by at least 2/3 of the nodes.

Comment: thanks @Matt can you explain what you meant by "We can have k > 2N/3 as long as N>=6"

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot++ceil(3n+%2F+(n%2B3)),+2n%2F3+for+n+from+0+to+20

Comment: should be *k < 2N/3*.  fixed